# Google Charts Unexpectedly Drawing A Trendline

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Using Google Charts ([Combo Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)). It appears to be automatically drawing a trendline below the cumulative line.

I know I can add trendlines. But I haven't and Google Charts is adding one anyway! How do I stop it from doing this?

[image: Example]

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'en_GB'});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                  [[{"type":"date","label":"Period"},"Order QTY","Revenue","Target (Revenue)","Cumulative","Target (Cumulative)"],["Date(2023, 9, 01)",6,126.3,3733.3333333333335,126.3,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 02)",14,4925.46,3733.3333333333335,5051.76,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 03)",21,16751.65,3733.3333333333335,21803.410000000003,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 04)",20,774.18,3733.3333333333335,22577.590000000004,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 05)",19,7702.63,3733.3333333333335,30280.220000000005,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 06)",26,5711.16,3733.3333333333335,35991.380000000005,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 07)",7,101.71,3733.3333333333335,36093.090000000004,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 08)",7,239.8,3733.3333333333335,36332.89000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 09)",32,8148.77,3733.3333333333335,44481.66,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 10)",14,1256.23,3733.3333333333335,45737.89000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 11)",38,5964.22,3733.3333333333335,51702.11000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 12)",26,1883.59,3733.3333333333335,53585.700000000004,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 13)",21,10981.02,3733.3333333333335,64566.72,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 14)",12,263.63,3733.3333333333335,64830.35,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 15)",8,136.66,3733.3333333333335,64967.01,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 16)",32,1238.84,3733.3333333333335,66205.85,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 17)",27,8939.29,3733.3333333333335,75145.14000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 18)",37,6082.73,3733.3333333333335,81227.87000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 19)",26,7123.39,3733.3333333333335,88351.26000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 20)",29,2875.15,3733.3333333333335,91226.41,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 21)",8,68.99,3733.3333333333335,91295.40000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 22)",5,20,3733.3333333333335,91315.40000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 23)",23,7521.06,3733.3333333333335,98836.46,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 24)",12,494.32,3733.3333333333335,99330.78000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 25)",17,3556.01,3733.3333333333335,102886.79000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 26)",22,1168.64,3733.3333333333335,104055.43000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 27)",17,2480.15,3733.3333333333335,106535.58,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 28)",5,332.6,3733.3333333333335,106868.18000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 29)",10,99.95,3733.3333333333335,106968.13,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 30)",17,2680.08,3733.3333333333335,109648.21,112000],["Date(2023, 8, 30)",0,0,3733.3333333333335,0,112000]]        );

        var options = {
          title : 'Last Month',
          seriesType: 'bars',
          vAxis: {
            title : 'Revenue',
            format: '£#,##0'
          },
          hAxis: {
            format: 'd'
          },
          series: {
            0: { // order qty
              visibleInLegend: false,
              color: '#D3D3D3',
              targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            1: { // revenue
              color: '#cf0800',
            },
            2: { // revenue target
              type: 'line',
              visibleInLegend: false,
              lineWidth: '1',
              color: '#cf0800'
            },
            3: { // cumulative
              type: 'line',
              targetAxisIndex: 2
            },
            4: { // cumulative target
              type: 'line',
              visibleInLegend: false,
              lineWidth: '1',
              targetAxisIndex: 2,
              color: '#304991',
            },
          },
          vAxes: {
            1: {
              title: '',
              textPosition: 'none'
            },
            2: {
              title: 'Cumulative'
            }
          },
          colors:['#cf0800', '#304991']
        };

        var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div_655b2ffdb9f5d' );
        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(chart_div);
        
        // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
       /*google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
          chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
          console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
        });*/
        
        
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    
    <div id="chart_div_655b2ffdb9f5d" style="width:600px;height:200px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
```

Here's the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck2s0db3/). I have slimmed it down as much as I can and removed almost everything and this weird blue line below the cululative line will not go away.

I thought it might be something to do with the `series: {}` section. But I think I've tried every permutation I have read on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "*weird blue line below the cumulative line*" is not a trendline.

it is a line connecting the last data point in the data table to the first,
because the data rows are out of order.

the last row is for SEP, where all rows before are for OCT.

so, you either need to move the SEP row to be first in the data table,
or sort the data table before drawing...

```
data.sort({column: 0});  // sort by date column
```

see following working snippet...

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'en_GB'});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                  [[{"type":"date","label":"Period"},"Order QTY","Revenue","Target (Revenue)","Cumulative","Target (Cumulative)"],["Date(2023, 9, 01)",6,126.3,3733.3333333333335,126.3,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 02)",14,4925.46,3733.3333333333335,5051.76,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 03)",21,16751.65,3733.3333333333335,21803.410000000003,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 04)",20,774.18,3733.3333333333335,22577.590000000004,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 05)",19,7702.63,3733.3333333333335,30280.220000000005,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 06)",26,5711.16,3733.3333333333335,35991.380000000005,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 07)",7,101.71,3733.3333333333335,36093.090000000004,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 08)",7,239.8,3733.3333333333335,36332.89000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 09)",32,8148.77,3733.3333333333335,44481.66,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 10)",14,1256.23,3733.3333333333335,45737.89000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 11)",38,5964.22,3733.3333333333335,51702.11000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 12)",26,1883.59,3733.3333333333335,53585.700000000004,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 13)",21,10981.02,3733.3333333333335,64566.72,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 14)",12,263.63,3733.3333333333335,64830.35,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 15)",8,136.66,3733.3333333333335,64967.01,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 16)",32,1238.84,3733.3333333333335,66205.85,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 17)",27,8939.29,3733.3333333333335,75145.14000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 18)",37,6082.73,3733.3333333333335,81227.87000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 19)",26,7123.39,3733.3333333333335,88351.26000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 20)",29,2875.15,3733.3333333333335,91226.41,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 21)",8,68.99,3733.3333333333335,91295.40000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 22)",5,20,3733.3333333333335,91315.40000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 23)",23,7521.06,3733.3333333333335,98836.46,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 24)",12,494.32,3733.3333333333335,99330.78000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 25)",17,3556.01,3733.3333333333335,102886.79000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 26)",22,1168.64,3733.3333333333335,104055.43000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 27)",17,2480.15,3733.3333333333335,106535.58,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 28)",5,332.6,3733.3333333333335,106868.18000000001,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 29)",10,99.95,3733.3333333333335,106968.13,112000],["Date(2023, 9, 30)",17,2680.08,3733.3333333333335,109648.21,112000],["Date(2023, 8, 30)",0,0,3733.3333333333335,0,112000]]        );

        var options = {
          title : 'Last Month',
          seriesType: 'bars',
          vAxis: {
            title : 'Revenue',
            format: '£#,##0'
          },
          hAxis: {
            format: 'd'
          },
          series: {
            0: { // order qty
              visibleInLegend: false,
              color: '#D3D3D3',
              targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            1: { // revenue
              color: '#cf0800',
            },
            2: { // revenue target
              type: 'line',
              visibleInLegend: false,
              lineWidth: '1',
              color: '#cf0800'
            },
            3: { // cumulative
              type: 'line',
              targetAxisIndex: 2
            },
            4: { // cumulative target
              type: 'line',
              visibleInLegend: false,
              lineWidth: '1',
              targetAxisIndex: 2,
              color: '#304991',
            },
          },
          vAxes: {
            1: {
              title: '',
              textPosition: 'none'
            },
            2: {
              title: 'Cumulative'
            }
          },
          colors:['#cf0800', '#304991']
        };

        var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div_655b2ffdb9f5d' );
        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(chart_div);
        
        // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
       /*google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
          chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
          console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
        });*/
        
        data.sort({column: 0});  // sort by date column
       
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    
    <div id="chart_div_655b2ffdb9f5d" style="width:600px;height:200px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
```